# Floating Draggable Box Disappearing on Resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, draggable

I am trying to create a floating window that stays within the margins on resize:

You can check out the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/jxgUU/6/

How do I accomplish this?

```
$(function()
{
    $("#result").draggable();
});    

#result 
{ 
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:375px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    left:75%x;
    top:100px;
    margin-left: -10px;     
    margin-top:  -50px;   
    cursor:move;
    color:black;
}

<div id="result"  class="ui-widget-content" >
    <div style="background-color:#096db5;color:white;font-size:9px;text-align:center;">
        click window to drag
    </div>
    <div id="info">
        blah
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Think we need some more information here. Also, I assume your fiddle should be using jQuery UI (like so http://jsfiddle.net/jxgUU/16/)

Comment: Also, you're setting `position:absolute` for your `draggable`. I don't think this will work...

Comment: @ Inrbob- I put the Jquery UI includes in -- but it's not saving in the jsfiddle.... assume that draggable is working... i just don't know how to make the box stay in its boundaries...

Comment: @ Lee Taylor - if I do relative it disappears off the screen... and when I actually find it and click on it the box moves away. fixed, inherit, etc. all do the same as absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a script that will automatically center the box when it hits an margin
on resizing.

source:

http://jqueryui.com/position/#default

this is the final code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#result").position({
        of: "#wrapper",
        my: "center  middle",
        at: "center middle",    
        collision: "fit flip"
    })//$("#result").position({
 });//$(window).resize(function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option:

```
$("#result").draggable({ containment: "window" });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jxgUU/18/)**

Comment: Thanks. That's great. I'm still having the resizing issue though.

Comment: What's not happening that you need to happen in the demo?

Comment: When I resize the window- the box is hidden. I'd like it to be viewable.